# Java initialize large array with Max value

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic, initialization

How can I initialize an array of size `1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000` of all `Integer.MAXVALUE`?

for example, I want to make this `int[][][][]dp = new int [1000][1000][1000][1000];` all have max value as later I need to compare a minimum.

I tried

```
int [] arr = new int arr[N];
Arrays.fill(arr,Integer.MAXVALUE);
```

but it doesn't work with multidimensional arrays, can anyone help?

Comment: You want to fill every value in an array that has one trillion possibilities?

Answer (score 12):

You'll have to do this to fill your multi-dimensional array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dp.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dp[i].length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < dp[j].length; k++) {
            Arrays.fill(dp[i][j][k], Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        }
    }
}
```

You won't however be able to initialize `new int[1000][1000][1000][1000]` unless you have at least **3.64 terabytes** of memory. Not to mention how long that would take if you did have that much memory.

Answer (score 2):

You need something very specialized like [Colt](http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) to generate what is called a [Sparse Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). You need to alter your logic slightly, instead of testing against a `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you test to see if something exists at a location ( defaults to ZERO ), if it doesn't then consider it `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and leave it alone.

This assumes you only insert a fraction of the possible data with values `< Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Answer (score 0):

fill will need as arguments the array and the values to fill per dimension. Say fill(array, 0,0,0) or in your case fill(array, maxValue, maxValue, maxValue).

Cheers,